# Optimising Recursion Problem for calculating Super Digits

Tags: c++, recursion

I have correctly written the program for getting the superdigit of a large number (long long) but can't seem to pass some cases due to timeout and abort calls. Please suggest some optimizations to improve the runtime of my program:

```
int superDigit(long long m) {
    int d=countDigit(m);
    if(d==1){
        return m;
    }
    long s=sumDigit(m);
    return superDigit(s);

}

//utility functions to calculate digit count and sum of digits

int countDigit(long long n) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 
    while (n != 0) { 
        n = n / 10; 
        ++count; 
    } 
    return count; 
}

long sumDigit(long long n) 
{ 
    long sum = 0; 
    while (n != 0) {
        sum += n % 10; 
        n = n / 10;  
    } 
    return sum; 
}
```

**Theory:** A superdigit is defined by the following rules:

- If x has only 1 digit, then its super digit is x
- Otherwise, the super digit of x is equal to the super digit of the sum of the digits of x

**For example:**

1. super_digit(9875):      9+8+7+5 = 29 ,then
2. super_digit(29):        2 + 9 = 11   ,then
3. super_digit(11):        1 + 1 = 2    ,then
4. super_digit(2):         = 2

Comment: If the number is less than and equal to 0 . What will be the super digit ?

Comment: BTW, what you are calculating is the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only looping over the digits once per `superDigit` call and avoiding recursion should make it faster. Something like this:

```
long long superDigit(long long m) {
    long long sum;
    while(true) {
        sum = 0;
        while(m != 0) {
            sum += m % 10;
            m /= 10;
        }
        if(sum >= 10)
            m = sum;
        else
            break;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you need support for repeated sequences, like 593 10 times (which is usually too big for a `long long`) you could add a wrapper like this:

```
long long superDigit(long long m, int times) {
    long long r = superDigit(m) * times;
    if(r >= 10) r = superDigit(r);
    return r;
}
```

For numbers small enough to fit in a `long long`, you can check that it works. Example:

`superDigit(148148148) == superDigit(148, 3)`

If you need support for large numbers that are *not* repeated sequences, you could add yet another overload, taking the number as a `std::string`:

```
long long superDigit(const std::string& m) {
    long long sum = 0;  
    for(auto d : m) sum += d - '0';
    if(sum >= 10) return superDigit(sum);
    return sum;
}
```

And you can check that it's also getting the same result as one of the previous overloads:

`superDigit(593, 10) == superDigit("593593593593593593593593593593")`

Comment: abort called for 8/10 cases.

Comment: m=593593593593593593593593593593 or 593 repeated 10 times. The actual input involves a number and the times it is repeated to get the final number.

Comment: sizeof(long long)=8

Comment: Then you can never store that number in `m`.

Comment: What storage container should I use then?

Comment: @harshrd If "The actual input involves a number and the times it is repeated to get the final number", than the input would be 593 and 10, so the first sum would be (5 + 9 + 3)*10 and there's no need to actualy calculate the first m, I'm I right?

Comment: This may be easier by treating the number as a string:  `int numeric_digit = text[i] - '0';`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the last overload takes a string.

Comment: @harshrd Did you try using it with the two extra overloads?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting abort call for value of m! If the value of m is 0, then the recursion will continue lifetime. And if the value of m can be negative then take care the problem for negative values too.

Please check it!

```
int superDigit(long long m) {
    if(m<=9)return m; //  handling case 0
    int d=countDigit(m);
    if(d==1){
        return m;
    }
    long s=sumDigit(m);
    return superDigit(s);

}
```

Comment: abort called for 8/10 cases.

Comment: Can you provide any test case or  the problem link?

Comment: m=593593593593593593593593593593 or 593 repeated 10 times. The actual input involves a number and the times it is repeated to get the final number.

Comment: But it will overbound long long !! You can  store about upto 10^18 in long long .

Comment: Your suggested fix makes the ’countDigits’ call completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a problem with a '0'. It gets into an endless loop that is terminated if the call stack overflows (if your compiler does not eliminated the tail recursion).
The digit count helper function is completely unnecessary

```
int superDigit(long long m) {
  if(m<10){
    return m;
  }else{
    int s = 0;
    do {
      s += m % 10;
      m = m / 10;
    }while (m > 0);
    return superDigit(s);
  }
}
```

You can eliminate the recursion by yourself by putting the whole thing into a loop.

```
int superDigit(long long m) {
  while (m >9){
    int s = 0;
    do {
      s += m % 10;
      m = m / 10;
    }while (m > 0);
    m = s;
  }
  return m;
}
```

But recursion looks a bit more self explaining and modern compiler should be able to eliminate the tail recursion either.